# Markdown to LaTeX conversion with a custom preamble using Pandoc

Tags: conversion, latex, pandoc

I know that I can use the `-H` or `--include-in-header` commands to include a custom preamble in the generated output. The problem is now that [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/try) includes my preamble but puts another preamble in front of it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\ifxetex
  \usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\else
  \ifluatex
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \else
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \fi
\fi
\ifxetex
  \usepackage[setpagesize=false, % page size defined by xetex
              unicode=false, % unicode breaks when used with xetex
              xetex]{hyperref}
\else
  \usepackage[unicode=true]{hyperref}
\fi
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true, pdfborder={0 0 0}}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}  % prevent overfull lines
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

[... my preamble ...]
```

I know that this is the default LaTeX preamble (`default.latex`) that Pandoc loads from its `templates` folder. The same thing happens when I'm using `--include-after-body` with `\end{document}`.

This is the command I'm using:

```
pandoc -o output.tex input.txt --include-before-body=header.tex --include-after-body=footer.tex
```

Answer (score 24):

As you have discovered, `--include-in-header` adds text into the preamble specified in Pandoc's LaTeX template. There are a few ways to do what you are trying to do.

1. If you would like a completely custom preamble, you need to specify a template file using

   ```
   pandoc -o output.tex --template=FILE input.txt
   ```

   The template can have variables (such as `$title$` and, more importantly, `$body$`) and conditionals. If you would like some inspiration, you could check out the default template using the command

   ```
   pandoc -D latex
   ```
2. If you want to use a new template once and for all, you can make one, call it `default.latex`, and put it in the templates directory (`~/.pandoc/templates/` on a unix machine). In this case, you need to specify that you want to use a template by calling

   ```
   pandoc -o output.tex --standalone input.txt
   ```
3. If you would rather not deal with templates at all, you can just run

   ```
   pandoc -o output.tex input.txt
   ```

   and the result will be a bare LaTeX document, that is, without a preamble, `\begin{document}` or `\end{document}`. Then you can add a preamble yourself. Note that any metadata (title, author) will be lost when using this method.

Full details on how to make and use templates can be found in [Pandoc's excellent man page](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html).

Answer (score 3):

See also this answer on tex.stackexchange [Adding headers and footers using Pandoc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139205/44254)

> With [pandoc 1.12.x](http://code.google.com/p/pandoc/downloads/list) and it’s new [YAML metadata](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-yaml_metadata_block) capabilities you could add all the information and all LaTeX-code you need in your markdown document like this:

```
---
title: Test
author: Author Name
header-includes: |
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhead[CO,CE]{This is fancy}
    \fancyfoot[CO,CE]{So is this}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
abstract: This is a pandoc test . . . 
---

# This is a test

Lorem ipsum....
```

> That way you don't have to modify the template, simply calling `pandoc doc.md -o doc.pdf` will suffice.